# Android скроллинг данных таблицы

Tags: java, android

Имеется таблица, можно ли для него сделать вертикальный и горизонтальный скроллиг, но только для для данных, кроме (верхняя строка - названия столбцов; первый ряд - название строчек).

Хочу что при скроллинге вертикально, названия столбцов всегда были видимыми, а при скроллинге горизонтально - название строчек в 1 столбце?

К тому же таблица должна создавать программно, так как каждый раз количество данных меняется

Comment: может создать две таблицы? одна для названий столбцов с одной строкой, другая для данных

Comment: @TimurVI и отдельно еще таблицу 1 столбца (названия строк)?

Comment: состав с названиями столбцов и строк постоянный?

Comment: нет, все подгружаться будет из БД, как и количество

Comment: в смысле может быть три столбца может пять и так далее?

Comment: по моему то, что вам [нужно](https://www.androidcode.ninja/android-scroll-table-fixed-header-column/)

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: есть хорошее готовое решение вашего вопроса https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView

Comment: Во всех случаях они используют фиксированное количество столбцов

Answer (score 0):

Создайте новый `.xml` файл в `res/layout`.

**.xml:**

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My attribute 1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="My attribute 2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_records"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**А дальше** в вашем `ViewHolder`(e) уже ставьте атрибуты `wrap_content` в `width`, `height`. Идея будет следующая, все виджеты будут рисоваться по высоте/ширине ваших данных, а не пытаться их вместить по ширине/высоте родителя.

[схожий вопрос с несколькими готовыми ответами.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119231/android-layout-how-to-implement-a-fixed-freezed-header-and-column)